# Linux: Redirect ipaddress to domain name

Tags: linux, networking

Is it possible to redirect local ipaddress to domain/subdomain name in linux?

I know it is possible with DNSMasq but my modem doesn't support that.

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect"? That makes no sense.

Comment: Editing `/etc/hosts` file, maybe?

Comment: for local testing. If subdomain.domain.com gets called I want to redirect it to localhost server.

Comment: You might want to consider followup questions at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing locally, edit your /etc/hosts file to route subdomain.domain.com to localhost:

```
127.0.0.1 subdomain.domain.com
```

DNS will resolve requests to subdomain.domain.com to your local server.

Going the opposite direction, you can setup a reverse proxy to route localhost to a staging or production environment such as subdomain.domain.com.  Edit httpd.conf or apache2.conf to include a ProxyPass.

For Apache, this requires mod_proxy module, loading modules proxy_module and proxy_http_module.

Of course, if you are not targeting specific environments, you could simply use relative paths.